# IMG and Text not aligning in Bootstrap Buttons in my navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

so I looked around Stackoverflow and couldnt find a solution to my problem

Strangely enough

I try here, [codepen](https://codepen.io/ffang0715/pen/NXNKjX)

```
<nav>
  <button class="btn btn-primary"> signed in as fermi 
    <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?
     name=Fermi+Fang&background=0D8ABC&color=fff&rounded=true">
  </button>
</nav>
```

text aligns center perfectly,

but on my live code, it doesn't

[img of my live code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV66P.png)

ok heres my [live code](https://codepen.io/ffang0715/pen/xpVErz)

```
   nav(class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-light bg-none 
px-sm-4 px-0 pr-2")
  button(id="container" class="navbar-toggler pr-0 ml-0 pl-3" 
type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" 
style="border-style:none")
    span(class="navbar-brand pointer mr-0")
      img(class="mr-1 nav-logo-white" src="/images/juu_logo_white.png" 
width="33" height="44.5" alt="")
      img(class="mr-1 nav-logo-black" src="/images/juu_logo_black.png" 
width="33" height="44.5" alt="")
      span(id="icon" class="fa fa-angle-down pr-0 mr-0" 
style="color:white")

  //buttons that are shown in mobile and not collapsed
  ul(class="navbar-nav d-inline d-md-none")
    if isLoggedIn
      div(class="input-group d-inline-flex d-md-none-flex pr-sm-3 pr-
1")
        input(type="text" class="form-control nav-search" id="nav-
search" aria-describedby="nav search" placeholder="Search for...")
        span(class="input-group-btn")
          button(class="btn btn-primary" type="button") <i class="fa 
fa-search"></i>

    else
      li(class="nav-item d-inline")
        button(type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" data-
toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal") Sign Up
      li(class="nav-item d-inline mr-sm-3")
        button(type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary m-1" data-
toggle="modal" data-target="#logInModal") Log In

  //navbar that collapses or hidden in mobile
  div(class="collapse navbar-collapse d-md-flex" 
id="collapsibleNavbar")
    a(class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block " href="/")
      img(class="mx-1 nav-logo-white ml-3" 
src="/images/juu_logo_white.png" width="33" height="44.5" alt="")
      img(class="mx-1 nav-logo-black ml-3" 
src="/images/juu_logo_black.png" width="33" height="44.5" alt="")
    if isLoggedIn
      div(class="input-group d-none d-md-inline-flex mr-auto col-lg-6")
        input(type="text" class="form-control" id="nav-search" aria-
describedby="nav search" placeholder="Search for...")
        span(class="input-group-btn")
          button(class="btn btn-primary" type="button") <i class="fa 
fa-search"></i>

    //shown in non mobile - will collapse when mobile
    ul(class="navbar-nav vertical ml-auto")
      li(class="nav-item")
        br(class="d-inline d-md-none") 

      li(class="nav-item ml-3 ml-sm-0 d-inline-block")
        button(type="button" class="btn btn-link m-1 btn-mob" data-t 
toggle="modal" data-target="#settingsModal") Settings
      if isLoggedIn
        li(class="nav-item ml-3 ml-sm-0 d-inline-block")
          button(type="button" class="btn btn-link m-1 btn-mob" data-
toggle="modal" data-target="#helpModal") Help 
        li(class="nav-item dropdown d-none d-md-inline-block ml-3 ml-
sm-0")
          button(type="button" class="btn btn-link m-1 btn-mob" data-
toggle="dropdown" ) Signed in as #{user.firstname} 
          ul.dropdown-menu
            li(class="nav-item")
              button(type="button" class="btn btn-link m-1" data-
toggle="modal" data-target="#userProfileModal") User Profile
            li(class="nav-item")
              a(role="button" class="btn btn-link m-1" href="/logout") 
Log Out
        li(class="nav-item ml-3 ml-sm-0 d-inline-block")
          button(type="button" class="btn btn-link m-1 btn-mob d-md-
none" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userProfileModal") User Profile
        li(class="nav-item ml-3 ml-sm-0 d-inline-block")
          a(role="button" class="btn m-1 btn-mob d-md-none" 
href="/logout") Log Out

    //hidden in mobile view
    ul(class="navbar-nav mr-2")
      if isLoggedIn

      else
        li(class="nav-item")
          button(type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1 d-none d-md-
block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal") Sign Up
        li(class="nav-item")
          button(type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary m-1 d-
none d-md-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logInModal") Log In
```

Any clue what might be causing the text and img in my buttons to not align correctly?

Thanks,

Comment: Looks like a padding or line-height issue but hard to tell without seeing your live code. Please post that relevant code here.

Comment: agree with @NathanielFlick please give the code of the issue coz your codepen example is fine

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve minimal, complete, and verifiable example. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask good questions.

Comment: let me post the live code when i get home~

thanks guys!!

Comment: The code in your live pen is missing all your html and css brackets formatting. Fix that so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `line-height` same size as `font-size`.
Maybe it works for you.